# Converting template content to color overlay

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, templates, xaml

I have a custom template, and I want to somehow take the output of `ContentPresenter` (imagine it as a bitmap), now strip RGB from that bitmap (so only alpha channel remains), and then set RGB on every pixel to white (preserve alpha channel). So how would you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a PixelShader + Effect on the ContentPresenter if it needs to be a 'live' effect.

See the [Shazzam tool](http://shazzam-tool.com/) to easily create the sources for the effect and the PixelShader.

```
sampler2D Texture1Sampler : register(S0);

//-----------------
// Pixel Shader
//-----------------

float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR
{
    float4 color = tex2D( Texture1Sampler, uv );
    float4 alphaMaskColor = float4(color.a,color.a,color.a,color.a); //Pre-multiplied Alpha in WPF
    return alphaMaskColor;
}
```

Comment: I've tried the code and it doesn't work. I've even tried replacing the `color.a` expression with `0`, but what I always get is just one big white rectangle ... it seems like the alpha channel is ignored altogether.

Comment: What is behind the image? Make sure you apply the Effect to the correct control.

Comment: Behind the image is glass (glass extended into the window). The glass should be visible, but there is just one big white rectangle, and the transparency is gone.

Comment: Do you see the correct image when you use alphaMaskcolor = float4(color.r, color.g, color.b,color.a); ? (Just to make sure the effect is ok)

Comment: Yes the image is correct. But once I change to the float4(1,1,1,color.a); all I see is just white rectangle.

Comment: I've even tried the SwapColors tutorial code and it works fine.

Comment: WPF uses pre-multiplied alpha try `float4(color.a,color.a,color.a,color.a)` or just `return tex2D( Texture1Sampler, uv ).aaaa;`